# Spark Naive Bayes ML OutofMemory Error - Prediction

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, naivebayes

I'm trying to build a Machine Learning program with Spark 1.6

I have started the Spark shell with the following settings:

> spark-shell --driver-class-path sqljdbc_6.0/enu/sqljdbc42.jar --driver-memory 25G --executor-memory 30G --num-executors 180 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.ui.port=4042 --conf spark.default.parallelism=100 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000`

My code works until I try to predict/use the model. 
After executing this code:

```
scala> val predictionAndLabel = test.map(p => (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
```

I get this error message:

> /usr/bin/spark-shell: line 41: 33686 Killed
>       "$FWDIR"/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" "$@"

I hope somebody can help me because I don't have any idea how I could make this code run smoothly!

Here is the Link to the complete full track of the error. 
https://app.box.com/s/w247yaoaiuogqot2zr76qjbwr9rzeb7b

Comment: How big is your `predict` output? This probably a issue of Too many data going to the Driver.

Comment: I am loading the Data from a MSSQL Server and i don´t know how big the input Data is. 

So i don´t know how big the predict output is going to be but the input Data is bigger than 1 Million Lines.

Comment: 1 million Lines will not take like 25 Gb of memory. Can you add the full track of the error in the Question? That will help to understand the issue.

Comment: Where do i find the full track?

Comment: I added the full track of the error in the Question.